# ORACLE DB: insert a row and return a variable to a scalar query

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle12c, executescalar

Environment:

- Oracle DB (12c)
- C# application to call the db

---

The expected outcome is to add new row into a table and return an id column which is auto-incremented using a sequence.

The caller is a c# application which uses executeScalar to execute the sql command.

I use this sql script:

```
DECLARE
  NEW_ID NUMBER;

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Users
  (username)
  VALUES ('newName')
  RETURNING userId INTO NEW_ID;
END;
```

which seems to be executing and does insert the new row.

**The issue**

The issue is that when this script is executed from the c# application using [executeScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it should return the first column of the first row of the returned result. Instead of receiving a value, **i receive null** (not DBNull).

Is the 'RETURNING' keyword not meant to be used for scalar queries or does the issue creeps somewhere else?

---

**EDIT:**

The trigger that is used to increment the column:

[image]

Comment: "an id column which is auto-incremented using a sequence". How is `userid` populated? With a SEQUENCE or with the new 12c IDENTITY column?

Comment: with a SEQUENCE

Comment: And there's a trigger on the table which populates the column with the sequence nextval?

Comment: yes exactly. I can see both by selecting 'user_sequences' and 'user_triggers'

Comment: Post your trigger.

Comment: I've updated the question with the trigger. i think that there is no problem with the trigger since it is working fine and is incrementing the id as expected.

Comment: Seems to me that one should wrap the PL/SQL script in a function or procedure and call that from C#